# Response javascript ajax with an object parse fail

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Where am i going wrong here!?

Javascript code:

```
var url = "/SitePages/AlertsHandler.aspx/GetAlert";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: '{alertId: \"' + alertId + '\"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.IncidentDesc);
    }
 });
```

C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetAlert(string alertId)
    {
        return MyJsonObject; // on debug --> {"IncidentDesc":"assdafsdaf","IncidentRecommend":"asdfsdaf"}
    }
```

And i get undefined on console... what did i miss here guys?

**Update**, Found the problem:

```
var data2 = JSON.parse(data.d);
console.log('IncidentDesc:' + data2.IncidentDesc);
```

Comment: Do you need to escape the inner double-quotes?

Comment: Basicly i used: var MyJsonObject= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myobject);

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @Richard Macarthy as i wrote in the end, i get "undefinned"

Comment: No, you wrote `console.log(data.IncidentDesc)` not `console.log(data)`

Comment: Remove `dataType: "json"`, debug the client code and see what is actually coming as `data`.

Comment: Maybe you should try sending actual json, `data: JSON.stringify({alertId: alertId}),`

Comment: Found it, thank you guys... Look my update in a sec

Comment: My answer was pretty close, but got down voted. Funny....

Answer (score 0):

`try this`

```
var url = "/SitePages/AlertsHandler.aspx/GetAlert";
var data={alertId: alertId};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.IncidentDesc);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to parse your JSON data, as it may be a string on response?

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(data.IncidentDesc);
```